Attaching a file that may still be in progress of saving
My situation is I convert a TIFF file to PDF file and email it out.
When I convert my TIFF I use do it manually by Ctrl+P Microsoft Print to PDF method.
I then start a macro in outlook to attach it to a new email.
Currently, I just check (using VBA code) to see if file size is larger than 0 and it attaches. If it's zero than I get a message and process is stopped.
If FFile.Size < 0 Then
   MsgBox "Attachment File Corrupted. Must convert the TIFF file to PDF again.", vbCritical
   End
End If

I want it to function such that when I start the macro, it waits for the file to fully save before attaching it.
I tried a loop, but when files are larger it will attach before the files are fully saved (thus corrupted)
For Each FFile In oDir.Items 'There should only be one file here
Do Until FFile.Size > 0 
Sleep 100 
Loop

ff = FreeFile  Open filePath For Append As #ff
This will raise an error when the file is currently being written or opened in another program. Remember to close #ff when opening the file succeeds. You will need error handling

A naïve (and not completely reliable) method would be to store the previous N file-sizes — when the size has not changed for N loops, assume that it has probably finished saving.

@hennep Sounds like it will work!
I'm just not too familiar with that type of code so might take me a bit to lock it in.
Thanks!

An alternative will be to check the size in a loop. If it stops increasing and you are happy with the threshold.
stabilityThreshold = 5
previousSize = FFile.Size

Do
    ' Sleep for a short duration to allow for file writing
    Sleep 100
    
    ' Get the current size of the file
    currentSize = FFile.Size
    
    ' Check if the size has changed
    If currentSize = previousSize Then
        stableCounter = stableCounter + 1
    Else
        stableCounter = 0 ' Reset counter if size changes
    End If
    
    ' Update previous size
    previousSize = currentSize
    
Loop While stableCounter < stabilityThreshold And currentSize >= 0


I am not on a windows network, could not test network permissions.
Maybe someone else can test a network file without write permissions.
For files that have the read-only bit set the function will return false, also for files on a linux network without write permissions.
When a file is completely written and closed the function will return true.
Option Explicit

Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Function GetFileSize(sFilePath As Variant) As Long
   Dim obj As Object
   GetFileSize = 0
   Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   If obj.FileExists(sFilePath) Then
      GetFileSize = obj.Getfile(sFilePath).Size
   End If
End Function
Function FileAvailable(sFilePath As String) As Boolean
    FileAvailable = False
    If Dir(sFilePath) <> "" And GetFileSize(sFilePath) > 0 Then
       Dim ff As Integer, er As Integer
       Do While True
          ff = FreeFile
          On Error Resume Next
          Open sFilePath For Append As #ff
          er = Err.Number
          On Error GoTo 0
          Select Case er
            Case 0 ' File is available
                 Close #ff
                 FileAvailable = True
                 Exit Function
            Case 70 ' File is locked, keep testing until available
                 Sleep 100
            Case 75 ' Read-only bit is set
                 FileAvailable = False
                 Exit Function
            Case Else
                 ' unexpected error, will be printed in the immediate pane
                 Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number, Err.Description
          End Select
       Loop
    End If
End Function
Sub test()
    Do While (True)
       If FileAvailable("V:\output.pdf") Then
          Kill "V:\output.bak"
          Name "V:\output.pdf" As "V:\output.bak"
          Exit Sub
       End If
    Loop
End Sub

You can extend the section below "Select Case ..." when errors appear in the immediate pane.

Tried this.
Even when it's in the process of saving (0KB) it goes straight to
Case 0 ' File is available

What tool do you use to open the tiff file?

It seems that the pdf creator opens a new file and immediately closes the file, probably to test file permissions. I have changed the code to first test for a file size and return true when grater than 0.

Black Ice Tiff Viewer 11.85 revision(1112)

@TWhite, I don't have the black ice tool, so I cannot reproduce the problem that way. If KJ is right and the output file is created in several bursts, then a combination of my code and Somnath's algoritm might be a solution. When the file is closed, wait for a period to see if the file is still growing in size. How much time can be determined experimentally. I don't have time to continue with the code before next weekend.

@hennep I think KJ is right too.
When I make it loop to attach when file size is over 0. It will (but not always) attach a file that's over 0kb (corrupted) that's not the max size it is when it fully completes saving. It's not noticeable by eye.
I think I will just have a message box come up for when file size = 0 and loop back to attaching (rechecking filesize) when I hit Okay.
It's never attached a corrupted file, except when I have it looping through waiting for the millisecond it's above 0kb.
Much less hassle then combining the two sets of code for pretty much the same outcome.
